# Post request returns 400 when using @requestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

i'm facing a weird problem when i try to post some data on my spring boot application

my body request class :

```java
public class KeyCloakUserRegister {

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    @UniqueInKeycloakConstraint
    private String email;


    private String password;

    public KeyCloakUserRegister(){}

    public KeyCloakUserRegister(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
 // getters and setters
}
```

my rest controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private KeycloakAuthenticationService keycloakAuthenticationService;

    @PostMapping("/create-user")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody KeyCloakUserRegister keyCloakUserRegister)
    {
        UserRepresentation user = keycloakAuthenticationService.createUser(keyCloakUserRegister);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
    ....
}
```

my security config

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }
}
```

this is my postman request

[image]

thanks for the help!

Comment: generally 400 means client side error , which essentially means that your request didn't reach your server or was invalid, Can you try by toggling cors setting ?

Comment: @NageshTripathi how do i add it?

Comment: It is probably something to-do with `@UniqueInKeycloakConstraint`, Just for trouble shooting purposes, can you remove it and add a `System.out.println("testing")` as the first line inside `createUser` method?

Comment: i figured out the problem, there was some password policies on keycloak and i didn't respect them on my request, so the server was returning a 400 HTTP status. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the problem, there was some password policies on keycloak and i didn't respect them on my request, so the server was returning a 400 HTTP status.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was fixed to make cors enable. If you remove the cors setting from your security configuration hopfully you could access it. If you find the same response, please share your response headers list.